# Can't update website built on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, google-cloud-platform

I have set up a Google Cloud website using a simple hello world tutorial in Python. I have then edited my code (just changed Hello world to put out another text), and I want to redeploy\update the changes from the cloud shell bash, but I cant figure out what the command is. I have tried

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update euphoric-graph-242609 \
```

I get no errors, but nothing happens. And the website still shows Hello World instead of the edited code.

Here are the steps I used to create the website, following the App Engine tutorial steps - starting with

```
git clone
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples

cd python-docs-samples/appengine/standard_python37/hello_world

virtualenv --python python3 ~/envs/hello_world

source ~/envs/hello_world/bin/activate

pip install -r requirements.txt

python main.py

gcloud app create

gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project euphoric-graph-242609
```

and I just now realised running the last code again would redeploy the app. But is this the correct way of just updating the app? Or should I use some update command like I tried first?

Comment: Can you give us more details? What service did you use to deploy your code in the first place? How did you initially deploy it?

Comment: I will update my post with more details

Comment: ...Which caused me to find a way to update the app - but not sure if running the deploy code again is the best way to update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project euphoric-graph-242609` again would re-deploy any changes.